# How to remake an existing random array to have unique elements (with restrictions)

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops

The question ask for a function that takes an array of integers pre-filled with random elements. The function goes through the array linearly and if any element is equal to any of the preceding elements, regenerate that element. This goes on  until the whole array is made of unique elements.

I know that this is very inefficient way of generating an array with unique elements but I wanted to give it a try. I wrote this code which falls into an infinite loop.

```
void makeUnique(int* const objArr, const int& size)
{
    int i = 1,j = 0;
    do {
        j = 0;
        while (j < i) {
            if (objArr[j] == objArr[i]) {
                objArr[i] = rand();
                --i;
                break;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    } while (i<size);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I suspect that when you get a match the inner loop decrement i and in effect you are running same loop again. So as long (regenerated numbers also) you get a match you will keep running.

Comment: You function works for me. Show how you are calling the function.

Comment: Consider using [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of a manual inner loop, and use standard C++ RNG classes from [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) instead of `rand()`